# How can I get code coverage for Travis-CI (C#)

Tags: c#, travis-ci, xunit, coveralls

I've been googling for solutions for quite a while now. I have a project on GitHub that uses Travis-CI for Continuous Integration. I want to have test coverage data in my Travis-CI log and for this I require a coverage tool.

My testing framework is xUnit. I've looked at the following page: https://github.com/csMACnz/Coveralls.net-Samples/tree/xunit-monocov-travisci because that is an example that uses TravisCI + xUnit however the packages seem to be outdated and there was no other example/tutorial I could find to get what I need.

Are there any people that have experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Current .travis.yml

```
language: csharp
solution: SenseGloveAPI/SenseGloveAPI.sln
install:
  - nuget restore SenseGloveAPI/SenseGloveAPI.sln
  - chmod +x SenseGloveAPI/packages/xunit.runner.console.2.2.0/tools/xunit.console.exe
  - sudo apt-get update 
  - sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2-examples
  - sudo apt-get install libglade2.0-cil-dev
  - sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-cil-dev
  - sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2
  - curl -sS https://api.nuget.org/packages/mono.cecil.0.9.5.4.nupkg > /tmp/mono.cecil.0.9.5.4.nupkg.zip
  - unzip /tmp/mono.cecil.0.9.5.4.nupkg.zip -d /tmp/cecil
  - cp /tmp/cecil/lib/net40/Mono.Cecil.dll .
  - cp /tmp/cecil/lib/net40/Mono.Cecil.dll /tmp/cecil/
  - git clone --depth=50 git://github.com/csMACnz/monocov.git ../../csMACnz/monocov
  - cd ../../csMACnz/monocov
  - cp /tmp/cecil/Mono.Cecil.dll .
  - ./configure
  - make
  - sudo make install
  - cd ../../csMACnz/Coveralls.net-Samples
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release SenseGloveAPI/SenseGloveAPI.sln
  - mono SenseGloveAPI/packages/xunit.runner.console.2.2.0/tools/xunit.console.exe SenseGloveAPI/SenseGloveAPIUnitTest/bin/Debug/SenseGloveAPIUnitTest.dll
```

This is how the example showed me to do what I want however Travis runs into an error when trying to build:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  gtk-sharp2 : Depends:
>   gtk-sharp2-examples (= 2.12.43-0xamarin7+debian7b1) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                 Depends: libglade2.0-cil-dev (= 2.12.43-0xamarin7+debian7b1) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: libgtk2.0-cil-dev (= 2.12.43-0xamarin7+debian7b1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: So stack overflow is a QA platform with specific scenarios. Can you start trying the implementation? Or provide code samples of what you've done so we can target specific issues?

Comment: I added what I have right now and the error it's causing, however I'm not sure if I am even on the right track which is why I asked without specifics.